# Will there ever be an edit counter?

Tags: feature-request, edits, profile-page

Since editing/revising questions and answers can earn one reputation now, I was wondering if there are any plans to display a counter somewhere on the profile page of how many edits a user made in total, and if there are any good reasons not to have one.

Comment: This has been asked several time, I'm looking for duplicates.

Comment: @Trufa: I did do a search and looked through the similar questions, but didn't see anything. If I missed one, I stand corrected.

Comment: I did a non-extensive one too, and had no luck! Sorry if I'm mistaken, but for some reason I'm sure I saw it before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime you can always just run a query on DataExplorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges

Comment: Which will under report the number because a) the data isn't live, but up to a month old and b) will miss the occasions where you've edited but someone else has edited later.

Comment: Thanks! @ChrisF: For the time being it's better than nothing...